# Are Nilaparvata nymphs winged?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

Source: [nbair.res.in](http://www.nbair.res.in/insectpests/Nilaparvata-lugens.php)

I'm wondering if the first individual on the left is a nymph. Even if not do *Nilaparvata sp* have wings in nymphal stage?

I'd appreciate any authentic source for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The family-level identification I had given I now see was unnecessary; the Wikipedia site for an economically important member of the genus (there called the **Brown planthopper**) is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_planthopper.  The species covered there has long- and short-winged forms; other members of the genus are probably similar.  All of the individuals in the photograph above are adult.  A late-instar nymph will have wing pads (not yet wings) which are fused to the thoracic segment to which they're attached (a life-cycle diagram with drawings of two nymphal instars -- there are probably more -- is found here: http://www.cpsskerala.in/OPC/pages/ricePestbrownplant.jsp [the eighth slide]). 
 So nymphs and short-winged adults won't be flying out of danger -- they'll be hopping away.

Comment: So the one on the left's a pre-adult (may be? of short winged form)? Comparing with the wings of short-winged *Nilaparvata sp* ([Photograph-6](http://www.cpsskerala.in/OPC/pages/ricePestbrownplant.jsp)) it's wings look different, too much gap between them.

Comment: The different colors of the animal's body and the wing makes me think that if the left-hand example is still a nymph (I'd have to test that idea on a local species--we're on opposite hemisheres) it reached adulthood within a day or two of the photo being taken (either wing-length form would still be possible).